# Extract constant value from a PCollection

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a connector which feeds me millions of entries. Some of those entries have a field `date` whose value is the same for all of them, but others don't. I need to get this value and set it to every entry on my pipeline.

If it was not a distributed pipepline, I would do something like this:

```
def set_date(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        mydate = entry.get('date')
        if mydate:
            break

    for entry in entries:
        entry['date'] = mydate
```

However, I have to treat each entry individually and not as a set, so I can not write the logic like this.

Moreover, we can not assure that every set of PCollection has at least one entry with the desired `date` field. It is unlikely, but it could still happen that all the entries on a PCollection does not have the `date` field, so the logic I have written above is not valid. I need to write some kind of PTransform which saves the `date` value to a class attribute, and on some type of "finally" clause, set the value on each entry.

What is the correct way of implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question! For Beam in a Batch pipeline you can do this with a *side input*. You would do something like this:

```py
def get_date(entry):
  if 'date' in entry:
    yield entry['date']

def put_date(entry, date):
  entry['date'] = date[0]
  return entry

with beam.Pipeline(...) as p:
  entries = p | ReadEntries(....)

  # First obtain the date from the entires.
  # We do this by outputting the date from the entries with a date,
  # and then we 'sample' one (this is a simple combiner that lets us
  # pick one of the dates - since they're all the same).
  date_pc = beam.pvalue.AsList(
      entries
      | beam.FlatMap(get_date)
      | beam.Combine(Sample.FixedSizeGlobally(1))

  # We then use the date_pc side input to join it into entries.
  dated_entries = entries | beam.Map(put_date, date_pc)
```

Let me know if this helps.

If none of the entries has a `date` attribute, then we may need to do something else. Happy to iterate!

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think about that. However, as you pointed, this solution would not fit the hypothetical case where none of the entries of a serialized PCollection contains the `date` field, would it?

Comment: As I know this value before runtime (it is actually an execution parameter), I have introduced it as a ValueProvider, and fed it as a side input to my function. I will post my solution just in case someone has the same situation as me, but I will mark yours as correct as it is a more general one. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the `date` value I want to set to my entries before running my pipeline, I have added it as a `ValueProvier` and fed it to my `SetDate` PTransform as a side input. If it is not your case, you can try the answer marked as correct instead.

This is my final implementation:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--query',
            help='Query to retrieve from BigQuery acting as data source.')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--mydate',
            help='Date with %Y-%m-%d format of the entries we are processing.')

options = PipelineOptions()
args = options.view_as(CustomOptions)

def run():
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | "Read from BigQuery" >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
                                          query=args.query,
                                          use_standard_sql=True,
                                          flatten_results=False)
            | "Set date" >> beam.ParDo(SetDate(args.mydate))
        )

class SetDate(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, mydate):
        self.mydate = mydate

    def process(self, entry):
        if 'date' not in entry:
            entry['date'] = self.mydate.get()
        yield entry
```